# What is the expected behavior on the event LostKeyboardFocus?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

Using Visual Studio Professional 17.6.4 and .NET 6

I have a modified version of a `TextBox`:

```
 1 internal class ItemPropertyTextBox : TextBox
 2 {
 3     public string PrevText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
 4
 5     protected override void OnLostKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
 6     {
 7         base.OnLostKeyboardFocus(e);
 8         PrevText = Text;
 9     }
10 }
```

Using it in the app like this:

```
50 var tb = new ItemPropertyTextBox { Text = ..., PrevText = ... };
51 ...
52 tb.LostKeyboardFocus += (sender, e) =>
53 {
54     var oldVal = tb.PrevText;
55     var newVal = tb.Text;
56     ...
57 };
```

The problem is that line `8` (assignment of `PrevText`) is called before line `54`, which is not what I expected.

If I modify the code to the following, everything works as expected, line `54` is called before line `16` (assignment of `PrevText`).

```
 1 internal class ItemPropertyTextBox : TextBox
 2 {
 3     public event EventHandler<KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs>? AfterEdit;
 4
 5     public string PrevText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
 6
 7     protected override void OnLostKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
 8     {
 9         base.OnLostKeyboardFocus(e);
10         OnAfterEdit(e);
11     }
12
13     private void OnAfterEdit(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
14     {
15         AfterEdit?.Invoke(this, e);
16         PrevText = Text;
17     }
18 }

50 var tb = new ItemPropertyTextBox { Text = ..., PrevText = ... };
51 ...
52 tb.AfterEdit += (sender, e) =>
53 {
54     var oldVal = tb.PrevText;
55     var newVal = tb.Text;
56     ...
57 };
```

Is this a bug somewhere, or is this the expected behavior?

Comment: @SirRufo I was wondering why line 8 was hit before line 54. I did not wonder if `OnWhateverHappened` was called before the event handlers.

Comment: @SirRufo Thanks for your efforts, but you must have misunderstood the question. Based on your fiddle, I suspect that you also have misunderstood the usage/naming of `OnWhateverHappened`. Please see [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/) for info.

Comment: @SirRufo I definetly wanted to know what was supposed to happen with a `TextBox`. Because for another event, such as `TextChanged` it behaves as I expected. But `LostKeyboardFocus` behaved differently, and I was curious if there was some particular reason for that, or if it is a bug.

Comment: @SirRufo Thanks for the tip, but I have already done that without observing anything special. If this is indeed a bug, it might have to do with Visual Studio. I have seen other bugs earlier that have disappeared after updating VS. What would be a useful comment, was if someone with another version of VS have tested this code and posted their result.

Comment: @SirRufo The problem I observed was that not all event handlers were called before the next line after `base.OnLostKeyboardFocus(e);` was called. This is a different behavior from e.g. the `TextChanged` event. If you have the opportunity, could you explain why these behave differently? (I totally understand if this question might appeared as a basic "how do events and event handlers work" type of question, but that was not the case :))